# How to raise a ticket with Microsoft for SharePoint 2013 On Premise?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to raise a ticket for SharePoint 2013 library.
How to raise a ticket with Microsoft for SharePoint 2013 On Premise?

Answer (score 0):

you create a support ticket by visiting this site : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hub/4343728/support-for-business and you have to pay for the support ticket.

or visit this link: https://premier.microsoft.com/ and you need the access ID (you get it when you company have a support agreement with MSFT).