# Workflow Manager Offline Installation Dowloading Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, workflow-manager, workflow-manager-farm

I am trying to install Workflow Manager on one of our SharePoint server where Internet is not available. So as part of Offline Installation I am downloading the WPI 5.1 bits and Workflow Manager 1.0 CU2 on a different machine, However while downloading its required setup files, I am getting below Error.

[image]

```
Processing product entry: 'ISAPIExtensions'.
Processing product entry: 'ISAPIFilters'.
Processing product entry: 'ASPNET'.
Processing product entry: 'IIS7'.
Processing product entry: 'WindowsImagingComponent'.
Processing product entry: 'WindowsInstaller31'.
Url 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/5/4852c63a-cf27-4e83-baad-47b8372e9e9b/WindowsServer2003-KB898715-x64-enu.exe' returned HTTP status code: 404
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Failed to download file: 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/5/4852c63a-cf27-4e83-baad-47b8372e9e9b/WindowsServer2003-KB898715-x64-enu.exe'.
Download of product 'WindowsInstaller31 failed. Failed to download file: 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/5/4852c63a-cf27-4e83-baad-47b8372e9e9b/WindowsServer2003-KB898715-x64-enu.exe'.
Processing product entry: 'NetFxExtensibility45'.
Processing product entry: 'ASPNET45'.
Processing product entry: 'ManagementService'.
Processing product entry: 'WindowsAuthentication'.
Processing product entry: 'WorkflowClient'.
Processing product entry: 'IIS51'.
Processing product entry: 'IIS60'.

Created snapshot '1' at 'D:\WorkflowManager\feeds\v001'.
Updated latest snapshot at 'D:\WorkflowManager\feeds\latest'.

Some operations failed, see the detailed error messages for more information:
Download of product 'WindowsInstaller31 failed. Failed to download file: 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/5/4852c63a-cf27-4e83-baad-47b8372e9e9b/WindowsServer2003-KB898715-x64-enu.exe'.
Skipping download of product 'NETFramework4': required dependency 'WindowsInstaller31' failed.
Skipping download of product 'ASPNET_REGIIS': required dependency 'WindowsInstaller31' failed.
Skipping download of product 'WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0': required dependency 'WindowsInstaller31' failed.
Skipping download of product 'NETFramework4PU3': required dependency 'WindowsInstaller31' failed.
Skipping download of product 'WindowsManagementFramework': required dependency 'WindowsInstaller31' failed.
Skipping download of product 'ServiceBus': required dependency 'NETFramework4PU3' failed.
Skipping download of product 'WorkflowManager': required dependency 'NETFramework4PU3' failed.
Skipping download of product 'WindowsFabricV1RTM_1_0_944_0': required dependency 'WindowsInstaller31' failed.
To use the new offline feed, please run the following from the command line:
WebPiCmd.exe /Install /Products:<products you want> /XML:<Offline main feed>
Done !
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with offline installation as the download never got completed.

You can try this.

1. Run the WPI setup on the machine having internet and select Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh (CU2) to install
2. It will download WFM and all of its components in below directory

> %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers
> 3. Copy the missing files from above path to the download directory of your offline installation.
> 4. Now copy all offline media, put it in the server where the installation is required and then try the offline installation commands. (follow Julie's suggested article)

In case that do not work, the second possible way could be to install all the prerequisites manually one by one and run the Workflow Manager installation from PowerShell.

Check [**this**](https://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2021/02/download-file-failed-signature.html) article on manual installation of Workflow Manager.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This sounds workable. I will try and mark this as answer if worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue when install the ServiceBus and WorkflowManagerRefresh offline in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31477.installing-workflow-manager-offline.aspx):

[image]

We suggest you open a ticket from Microsoft to check if the file link has been changed and caused it could not be found while downloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have a subscription.

Comment: Please refer to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281578/how-to-raise-a-ticket-with-microsoft-for-sharepoint-2013-on-premise